# Optocoupler to control pi power supply

Tags: power, power-supply

I got an idea of using a ATtiny85 and an optocoupler to control my raspberry pi's power supply. The optocoupler is the L1513. Would this be possible?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fijcLo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you intend to use an **opto**coupler to turn on the power to a RPi?

Assuming this is the case I don't think this would be the best way to accomplish this. Optoisolators are commonly used when there are different voltage levels on either side and/or the signals on either end may vary. This will not be the case for you. Your Atiny will be operating on 5V or 3.3V and the input power for the Rpi will be 5V. You may want to simply use a transistor, MOSFET or transistor operated relay board.

Learn All About optocouplers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator):

Comment: I'm confused. Would an optocoupler work, or would it get damaged?

Comment: It all depends on the optocoupler. I can't seem to find a datasheet for the  L1513. lets take a look at something that I can find the data sheet for:
[4n25](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf)

This technically would not work because as you can see in the **ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS** section the Ic (collector current) is 100mA. I have a RPi 2 and it draws about 200mA, so you can see the this optoislator is not ideal for the job. They generally do not handle large currents. In the applications it reads that it is suitable for: 'Reed relay driving'. Perhaps use a reed relay with the opto.